# Datanucleus JDO: how can i store a set of strings?

Tags: mysql, jdo, datanucleus

I am migrating a project from using JDBC to Datanucleus's implementation of JDO.

In the old architecture, there is a class that reads a number of strings from a database (the table contains only those strings, just one column with the unique constraint), does some work with them and either deletes them from that table and writes them to another one, or leaves them alone depending on the result of its work.

I don;t want to use schema generation because I might end up having to migrate the data from the old tables (which might not be that difficult) and I want to be more in control of the database structure.

So the question is: how do i either write a data object that would map onto a table of strings and, when asked, would return a set of strings, or turn the worker object into a mixture of data object and worker that can read a strings from that table? Or do i take a totally different approach altogether?

Answer (score 1):

A Set of Strings is easily enough defined using JDO following this page
http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_4_0/jdo/orm/one_to_many_set.html#join_nonpc

and you can use any form of JDOQL to query such like, for example

```
SELECT FROM Person WHERE addresses.contains(addr) && addr.matches(somePattern)
```

Comment: How can i then select some of the strings from the db? Sth. like "Select word from my_word_table where word like 'myword%';" and have those values in the set?

Comment: see update to answer, as could be found the JDO spec for example

Comment: I upvoted it, but didn't accept because it is not quite what i was looking for. I ended up creating a new class with just one field "word", and then i "mapped" it to my table containing strings. That way i can select the wrapped strings that match my patterns.